# Offline MVC 6 Application

Tags: sql-server, sqlite, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

This might be a doom question. I have an MVC 6 Entity Framework 7 application that I would like be accessible even if there is no internet access to the user.

I know that **might be impossible** since almost all my buttons and links send a request to the server (goes to the URL) and I know that by nature, web applications run on the server not on the client.

Is it possible to make my web application accessible offline? In other words to run the application on the client side?

Please note that this application works with a SQL server database but I have tried to use SQLite but I noticed that the SQLite database also runs on the server (It does not get copied to the client).

**When Offline.**
Basically, the users will login, capture information including images and save that information locally on their mobile phones and later upload that info to the server when they have internet access.

Currently everything is working if the user can access the live application from the server. But I would like to make it accessible offline as well.

This application will be used mainly for mobile phones.

Thank you so much.

Comment: It's possible with a JavaScript frontend application built on something like Angular. But it's a lot of work to cache all the offline actions.

Comment: You should look at native mobile apps. You can't run an ASP.NET application on a mobile device.

Comment: @NateBarbettini, Do you have any tutorials or examples that I can refer to?

Comment: @MikeBrind, my application is NOT traditional ASP.NET application. It is an MVC application of which it supports mobile devices including cell phones, tablets and it works in most web browsers. My application is already working on mobile devices, so I just need an offline solution.

Comment: @Linda, it's an ASP.NET application, whether you use MVC or Web Forms. It executes on a web server. It cannot execute on the client, be that a desktop, tablet or mobile device. Of course you can use a mobile phone to access an ASP.NET web site deployed to a web server, but it doesn't "execute" on the mobile device.

Comment: @MikeBrind, I agree with you completely. I found something that I think it might work. `localStorage`. It uses `javascript` to store information on the client device, then later I will get that information and transfer it to the server. However, the disadvantage with this solution is that I can only store up to 5MB of data on localStorage.

Comment: This is probably more like the direction you should be looking: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/206310/data-synchronization-in-mobile-apps-multiple-devices-multiple-users

Comment: @MikeBrind, Thank you so much.